# Bounds for Basin-Hoping method on a single variable function

Tags: python

For the Basing-Hoping method on a multivariable function with specific boundaries, I write the code as follows:

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
bnds = ((1, 100), (1, 100), (1,100))# the bounds

def F(X):# Multivariable function
    a,b,c = X[0],X[1],X[2]
    return a**2+b**2+c**2

x0 = [10., 10., 10.]
minimizer_kwargs = { "bounds":bnds }
minimum = opt.basinhopping(F, x0, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs)
print(minimum)
```

And it does gives the answer within the mentioned boundaries.

But my question is, if I follow the same pattern for a single variable function, I get an error saying that: "length of x0 != length of bounds".

The example that I used was:

```
bnds = ((1, 100))#  bounds

def F2(X):# Single variable function
    return X**2

x0 = [10]
minimizer_kwargs = { "bounds":bnds }
minimum = opt.basinhopping(F2, x0,minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs)
print(minimum)
```

Appreciate your help on how to resolve this issue..

Comment: try `bnds = (1,100)` instead of using double parenthesis. because it makes abounding function 2D.

Comment: @nipundeelakapathirage Well... That also didn't work. But looks like `bnds = [(1,100)]` works!

Comment: Okay. thank for the clarification!